# Необходимо, чтобы действие по кнопке "B" происходило только если нажата кнопка A? JS

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется следующая конструкция:

```
    <div class="rating__block">
        <div class="rating__btn"><div>1</div></div>
        <div class="rating__btn"><div>2</div></div>
        <div class="rating__btn"><div>3</div></div>
    </div>
    <a id="submit" class="rating__sibmit" href="#">Submit</a>
```

К элементу div c классом "rating__btn" при клике добавляется класс "active", не понимаю как правильно написать условие в конструкцию if...else. Хочу, чтоб при отсутствии класса "active" у "rating__btn", при нажатии на кнопку Submit появлялся alert(''), а если класс "active" присутствует совершалось действие(в моем случае добавляется класс).

```
if (к "rating__btn" добавился класс "active"){
    card.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
   }else{
    alert('Поставь рейтинг');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен [classList.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.rating__btn').forEach(el => {
  if (el.classList.contains('active')) {
    console.log('act 1');
  } else {
    console.log('act 2');
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="rating__block">
  <div class="rating__btn">
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="rating__btn active">
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="rating__btn">
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<a id="submit" class="rating__sibmit" href="#">Submit</a>
```